# Slow updating of UI with WPF and Oxyplot

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, oxyplot

What I'm trying to accomplish here is I want grab some data from a CSV file that I copy from one folder and put into a temp folder (so I don't tamper with the original).

Then I want to read in all the data from the CSV file and plot the last 2000 data points on a graph using a Scatter Series in Oxyplot (I want this to check for new data every 200 ms so I used a Dispatcher Timer). The issue I'm having is that the first few updates to the plot look great and it plots exactly how I want it to... however, after maybe 12 updates the graph does not update, or updates extremely slowly causing the UI to become unresponsive.

Below is my code for this part of the project...

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        viewModel = new View_Model.MainWindowModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;

        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTargetRendering;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AutoUpdateGraph()  //begins when a check box IsChecked = true
    {
        sw.Start();
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SleeveData sd = new SleeveData();          //class to deal with the data
        FileManagement fm = new FileManagement();  //class to manage the files

        string date = fm.GetDate();                //get the current date to use in finding the 
                                                   //most recent CSV file

        _newPath = fm.InitialFileSetup(date);      //create a new path for the temp file

        fm.RewriteFile(_newPath);                  //write the temp file to the temp path

        if (fm.IsFileLocked(_newPath) == false)   //checking if the file is being written to
        {
            IEnumerable<SleeveData> newSD = sd.GetMostRecentCSVData(_newPath); //getting the latest data from the temp file

            viewModel.LoadData(newSD); //updating the data on the graph
        }
    }
```

And here is the LoadData method in the MainWindowModel...

```
    public void LoadData(IEnumerable<SleeveData> newData)
    {
        var scatterSeries1 = new OxyPlot.Series.ScatterSeries
        {
            MarkerSize = 3,
            Title = string.Format("Sleeve Data"),
        };

        int j = 0;

        var zeroBuffer = new List<float>(new float[2000]);
        var fDiaDataBuffer = zeroBuffer.Concat((newData.Select(x => x.fDiameter).ToList())).ToList();
        var iDiaDataBuffer = zeroBuffer.Concat((newData.Select(x => x.IDiaMax).ToList())).ToList();

        for (int i = fDiaDataBuffer.Count - 2000; i <= fDiaDataBuffer.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            scatterSeries1.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(j, fDiaDataBuffer[i]));
            j++;
        }

        PlotModel.Series.Clear();
        PlotModel.Series.Add(scatterSeries1);
    }
```

I'm doing some funky stuff to get the latest 2000 points and add them to the graph.

Maybe I need to consider a background worker?

I might be going about this all wrong, and if I am I would love to know in which direction I should go! I'm fairly new to coding projects this large and ones that must run real time. Please go easy on me :) and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

Use a Stopwatch in your LoadData() method to see how long it's taking. You don't say how much data is in these files, but some of the Linq stuff looks like it could benefit from some optimisation - there are lots of `ToLists()` and repeated `Selects` on the same set of data. Something like this:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

... do your stuff

Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

You could also try a stopwatch in the timer delegate, to see how long an entire "cycle" takes, just in case it's taking longer than 200ms. I don't know if the DispatcherTimer can suffer from re-entrancy, where the timer fires again before the previous "tick" has completed, which would degrade performance.

The problem might lie with your charting component. I've had similar issues when working with large WPF DataGrids - creating the data isn't particularly taxing - it's the rendering that takes the time. At the end of LoadData() I see you clear down the chart series then repopulate it. I've found that doing this with the data source for a large DataGrid creates a "double-whammy", as it renders after the Clear(), then renders again after repopulating the data. I'm not familiar with OxyPlot but see if you can find an alternative approach, if feasible, e.g. re-using the series rather than clearing down and adding again.

If the poor performance does turn out to be OxyPlot, is purchasing a different chart component an option? I can thoroughly recommend SciChart, which we've been using for various high performance/high volume scientific charting applications (I'm not affiliated to them btw!).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did actually use a stopwatch to monitor how much time grabbing the data is taking, it gets progressively larger because the CSV file is constantly being written to (longest it took was almost 300ms, I just want my app to check for new data every 200ms). I'm not sure the size of the data is causing the issue because I only grab the last 2000 points and plot them. I think your right about the bottleneck existing in the rendering, although being inexperienced with C#, I'm finding it difficult to figure out how to add to the series. Also, those ToList()s are funky...

Comment: *finding it difficult to add to the series instead of wiping it out and rebuilding it completely. I want the graph to be a running style meaning newest data on the right hand side. When new data is received that data gets pushed to the left... this is the only way I could accomplish that.

Comment: @JoshRyan assuming lines are continually added to the file but never removed, how about keeping track of the last line number that you plotted. On the next timer tick, read the file and skip this number of lines then iterate through any remaining lines, create a ScatterPoint and add it to the existing series (something like `PlotModel.Series[0].Points.Add(...)'). If the number of points in the series is 2001 then `PlotModel.Series.RemoveAt(0)`, which will give you that "running" plot style. No need to clear down and recreate the entire series on each tick!

Comment: @JoshRyan I don't think there's much you can do about the file constantly growing in size. You've already found that it's causing problems as it gets larger, taking longer than the timer interval to process. Do you have any control over this file? Could you (potentially) clear it down after you've read it, or is it needed elsewhere? (if so, is it an option to back it up first, then clear it down?). Just some ideas...

Comment: I am actually copying the entire file to a temp folder every tick and then reading in that! Seems inefficient, but I couldn't think of any other way to not damage the original file (which is a fairly critical data file). This file is being written to every 2 minutes, so checking every 200ms is overkill. All of your ideas are great, I will try them. I appreciate your feedback. And answering one of your original questions, I have very limited budget for this project, purchasing SciChart wouldn't be an option...